# The issue is raised when trying to login

Tags: django-views

I created a login view successfully but using django-messages now I am having trouble login. I am wondering what could be the issue here.

```
def loginPage(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        messages.info(request, 'User does not exist')
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'Username or password does not exist')
context = {}
return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', context)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a login function somewhere in your code which I'm not sure of, but if you are using the [official django auth system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/), then you should rewrite your view with authenticate and remove login.

```
def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
      
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or password does not exist')
            context = {}
            return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', context)
```

Comment: That's certainly not the issue. The indentation erred when I paste the code here.